# Unable to remove commons-fileupload dependency from spring application

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm working on a spring application which has commons-fileupload dependency added. Since commons-fileupload version 1.4 (latest) have [CVE-2021-29425](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-29425) & [CVE-2020-15250](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2020-15250). from its dependencies it was decided to be removed from project. There are no direct code usages and it compiles fine after removing commons-fileupload. But tomcat throws following error in the startup.

```
 15-Feb-2022 16:39:47.612 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:755)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1177)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1925)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2509)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1819)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationFilterAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:782)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5130)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1415)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1223)
        ... 23 more
15-Feb-2022 16:39:47.613 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory [/home/ravindu/work/software/apache-tomcat-8.5.73/webapps/ROOT]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:759)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1177)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1925)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:755)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2509)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1819)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationFilterAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:782)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5130)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1415)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1223)
        ... 23 more
15-Feb-2022 16:39:47.613 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/ravindu/work/software/apache-tomcat-8.5.73/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [1,375] ms
```

pom.xml file is as follows

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven_project</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>project_maven</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>         
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <build.number>1.0-SNAPSHOT</build.number>
        <spring.version>4.3.30.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>datalayer_maven</artifactId>
            <version>${app.datalayer.build.number}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink </artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
                    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
                    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>bctsp-jdk14</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>toolchain</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <toolchains>
                        <jdk>
                            <version>1.7</version>
                        </jdk>
                    </toolchains>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> 
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Implementation-Version>${build.number}</Implementation-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>cobertura</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

There are no transitive dependencies for commons-fileupload as per the mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] com.app.:maven_project:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.app:appdatalayer_maven:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.faces:javax.faces-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.30.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.30.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.30.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.30.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.30.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.30.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.30.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.30.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.30.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.30.RELEASE:test
```

I noticed that spring-web is using [commons-fileupload](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.4/usages) but does that mean we have to manually add it as a dependency ?

Does anyone know why it produces this tomcat startup error ? Is it a direct dependency for tomcat or could that be any other dependencies depending on commons-fileupload ?.
TIA

Comment: Please show the full pom file...

Comment: @khmarbaise i have updated the Question with pom file

Comment: You have given the dependency in your pom.xml (commons-fileupload)

Comment: You have a `Filter` that contains a `FileUpload` field.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thanks for the answer . There was a org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter used in web.xml you helped me to find it.